# Azure verification with not my credit card

Tags: azure

I want to sign up for trial account, but I need to use not my credit card. I have not found any information if thats possible.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We have nothing to do with Azure accounts/payments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure-specific pricing/signup question. Nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found answer. Yes, it is possible

Answer (score -1):

You could buy one of those prepaid credit cards from the store. This way there's a hard limit and no other issues using a credit card number you rely on elsewhere.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This way is not working. Prepaid and virtual cards are forbidden by Microsoft.